# How does this monadic function in Haskell work?

Tags: haskell

I am struggling to wrap my head around this function**

```
  -- split at whitespace
  -- f "hello world" -> ["hello","world"]

  f =  takeWhile (not . null) . evalState (repeatM $ modify (drop 1) 
    >> State (break (== ' '))) . (' ' :)
    where repeatM = sequence . repeat
```

I am already struggling with understanding the state monad and the lack of Type signatures and the point free style make it even more confusing.

What is going on here?

** taken from [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Blow_your_mind)

Comment: First off, this code is really old. It needs updates to work with modern versions of transformers/mtl. Second, it's written really poorly, just in terms of formatting. It's like they were going for maximal obfuscation by not making it easy to distinguish the plumbing from the important logic.

Comment: @Carl I guess it is part of why I am struggling!

Comment: There seems to be a serious misunderstanding of the term "useful idiom" with regards to the contents of that page. Take a great deal of what's found on wiki.haskell.org with a huge grain of salt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`break (== ' ') :: String -> (String, String)` produces the longest prefix of the input string without whitespaces on the left, and the remaining suffix on the right. Clearly we want to somehow iterate this process to split a string into its words.

`State (break (== ' ')) :: State String String` views that function as a stateful computation. Remember `State :: (s -> (a, s)) -> State s a`, so the output state is the right component. So the initial state is the input string, and `break (== ' ')` viewed imperatively as a `State` action, `return`s the first word and updates the state to the remaining suffix.

Now compose that with `modify (drop 1)` to drop the next space, and repeat. Note that it appends to the input `(' ' :)` at the beginning, and starts with `modify`

```hs
(sequence . repeat) (modify (drop 1) >> State (break (== ' ')))
  :: State String [String]
  = do
                                -- current_state = " hello wold"
  modify (drop 1)
                                -- current_state = "hello world"
  s1 <- State (break (== ' '))  -- s1 = "hello"
                                -- current_state = " world"
  modify (drop 1)
                                -- current_state = "world"
  s2 <- State (break (== ' '))  -- s2 = "world"
                                -- current_state = ""
  modify (drop 1)
                                -- current_state = ""
  s3 <- State (break (== ' '))  -- s3 = ""
                                -- current_state = ""
  ...
```

`repeat` constructs an infinite list of the same two-step action `modify (drop 1) >> State (break (== ' '))`
`sequence` takes a list of actions and runs them, collecting the result in a list. Here I am handwaving, but because this is the lazy state monad (there is a strict one, and this is not it), things work out so that `sequence` can run an infinite list of action and produce the resulting infinite list of results on demand.

So you get an infinite computation as shown above, producing the infinite list of results of all `State (break (== ' '))` steps.

```
["hello", "world", "", "", ...]
```

`takeWhile (not . null)` is hopefully self descriptive: it **takes** elements from the list **while** they're **not empty**.

```
["hello", "world"]
```

Comment: Great explanation. Might be worth adding that it's a *bad* implementation; whether or not you like the style, it just doesn't work right when there could be multiple spaces in a row (because it can't distinguish between the null word "between" two spaces and the infinite sequence of empty strings it keeps producing once the input is exhausted). `f "hello  world"` is `["hello"]`

Comment: Great. Can you add the Type Signature to your function please?

Comment: @Ben Yes, it is just to understand some functions with an example. In this case, is there any way to fix the problem you have mentioned?

Comment: @Ben something like `dropWhile isSpace` instead of `drop 1`?

Comment: @matt Yeah, there are several options, but what would actually fix it depends on the desired behaviour. It requires actually thinking about what behaviour you actually *want* in all cases (*do* you want empty "words" between spaces, or drop all consecutive spaces? Do you want to split on just space characters, or any whitespace-ish character, or something else? etc etc).